# adding multiple existing folders and multiple existing files to Visual Studio project in single step

Tags: visual-studio, file, addition, directory

Does anyone have a way to add multiple folders and (existing) files within those folders to a Visual Studio project in a single step (or via macro)?  Let's assume all of the folders and files were copied/pasted into the project folder where they need to reside relative to the project folder, but are not actually stored in the .csproj or .vbproj file, which I believe is a requirement to compile those files into the solution/project.

This works great if you have a web application project in your solution, but not so well if you have a .csproj or .vbproj.  In that case, you must manually add folders (and nested folders), and add existing files and browse to each one individually, which can take a long time.

Comment: I think this needs an updated answer for vs 2017.

Comment: @jschmitter Feel free to answer if the answer should be different based on version.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the solution explorer, select the project, click the "Show All Files" button  - [image].

This will show all the files, even those not part of the project. You can now select all of these in the solution explorer (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click) then right click and go to "Include In Project".

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2013 (and possibly earlier) you drag the folder from windows explorer and drop it on the project in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Other answer given in this thread wouldn't work for me as the files I want to add (DTSX files) are in a different folder, and copying/moving them causes other problems. Here is what worked for me:

Using Visual Studio 2015, use Windows Explorer to locate the files you want to add to your project. Copy those files to the clipboard. If DTSX files are what you are dealing with, in the Solution Explorer right-click on SSIS Packages, and then click on Paste.